# Memory Error Occured while creating multi-hot-sequence(tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to run a problem of overfitting in my jupyter notebook but this error ouccered can anyone help me how to solve this problem. 
[image: Image of code]

Comment: Please post your code as code rather than as an image, cheers.

Comment: I've turned your link into an embedded image, but seriously: copypaste your code, don't screenshot it. Don't make life difficult for people who might be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Mohit, it seems your dataset is too heavy to handle, try reducing the batch-size in your code it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with less value Num_words value around 2000 and its work properly.. the main problem was my computer can't handle that much memory at that time due to which its show memory error

Comment: Yeah so reducing the batch size would affect the number of frames processed at that instance of time thereby reducing the memory usage.